# Finding the distance between two gears

Tags: triangles

I have the following problem:

[image]

In my class, we did a majorly complicated method to figure this out but I think there is a better way to do this...  Here is the exact problem:

**A belt fits snugly around the two circular pulleys shown.**

Find the distance between the centers of the pulleys.  Round to the nearest hundredth.

The method we used required that I create this huge triangle across the page.  It didn't sound like the best way to do it.  Does anybody have a "none-hacked" way to do it (as in, a more straight forward procedure)?

**EDIT**

I'm sorry about this, yes, the diagram is misleading, I had to recreate the image in an annoying program.  Yes, lines RS and line QP are both tangent to both circles.  Sorry about that, I never explained the context of the question.

Comment: Does **snugly** means the lines through $QP$ and $RS$ are tangent to both circles.  And hence $SNP$ and $RMQ$ are not straight lines?  Diagram is misleading in this respect.

Comment: @Eric Naslund Sorry, I just updated the details.  Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Good programs do draw things like this are GeoGebra and CarMetal, where you can define the RELATIONSHIPS between geometrical elements, add labels, etc, and take a screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that "fits snugly" means that PQ is tangent to both circles, at Q and P respectively: Note that the radii MQ and NP are both perpendicular to PQ (as it is tangent). This means that MQ and NP are parallel. Draw a line through N parallel to PQ, meeting MP at Q', say.

[image: Gears: Direct common tangent]

So QPNQ' is a rectangle, and NQ'=PQ=14 (in length). The part of MQ "above" Q', namely MQ', has length MQ - Q'Q = MQ - NP = 5 - 4 = 1.

This means that MN, the distance between the centres, is the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle MQ'N with MQ'=MQ-NP and Q'N=QP, so $$\text{MN} = \sqrt{(\text{MQ}-\text{NP})^2 + \text{QP}^2} = \sqrt{(5-4)^2 + 14^2} = \sqrt{197} \approx 14.04.$$

In general, if the length of the PQ-like part (distance between points of tangency) is $l$, and the circles have radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, then the distance between the centres is $\sqrt{l^2 + (r_1-r_2)^2}$.

Comment: Our resulting answer was 14.03 so you may be on to something (we may have rounded weird).  It's going to take me a minute to decipher your explanation though :)

Comment: Nope, you got it! :D

Comment: Well, taking a look though, how can we assume RQ and SP is a straight line?  They can't because one is smaller (the circles) so, for them all to be tangent, SNP appears to be **almost** a straight angle **or** RMQ could be **almost** a straight angle or even **both**.  I'm confused as to how you figured them parallel (MQ and NP).  I'll take another look at it.

Comment: Hmmm... OK, you are right, thanks so much!  I must just be a little bit slow, math class ended 3 hours ago and so must my brain :)

Comment: @DalexL: I did not assume RMQ and SNP are straight lines; in fact we don't need to care about R and S (about which we directly know nothing useful, anyway). MQ and NP are parallel because they are both perpendicular to PQ. Let me try drawing a figure, though I'm very bad at such tools...

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I eventually figured that out, thanks though for the comment :)

Comment: General note: I just discovered [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/), and it's awesome!